# Google Script IF Statement for text

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

I need to write a Google Scripts IF Statement but for TEXT not Numeric values. If cell x contains "Yes" then y else z.

Small syntax issue in line 2. I've tried everything I can find to fix. Please help!

```js
  var workingcell = activesheet.getRange(3, 4).getValue();
  if (workingcell == "Yes"){
    activesheet.getRange(4, 4).setValue("TASK - BC to be given access to IMS.");
  } else{
    activesheet.getRange(4, 4).setValue("TASK - BC to create Slack Channel.");
  }
```

Comment: Your variable "activesheet" isn't defined anywhere in the example script you posted. Check this page on [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post with the rest of your script so that we can troubleshoot it a lot more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function runTwo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,4,2,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  if (vA[0][0].toString().toLowerCase()=="yes"){
    vA[1][0]="TASK - BC to be given access to IMS.";
  } else{
    vA[1][0]="TASK - BC to create Slack Channel.";
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Here it is as an onEdit() function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart==4 && e.range.rowStart==3) {
    if(e.value.toLowerCase()=='yes') {
      e.range.offset(1,0).setValue("TASK - BC to be given access to IMS.");
    }else{
      e.range.offset(1,0).setValue("TASK - BC to create Slack Channel.");
    }
  }
}
```

If your not running function as in the first example or get a user edit in the second example then it's not possible.  There's no trigger that detects a change in a single cell.

You could use it as a cell function I suppose.  Like this:

```
function runTwo(A) {
  if (A.toString().toLowerCase()=="yes"){
    return "TASK - BC to be given access to IMS.";
  } else{
    return "TASK - BC to create Slack Channel.";
  }
}
```

Put it into `D4` as `=runTwo(D3)`

Comment: Thanks but this did not work :( It always returns the second option.

Comment: 'Yes' has to be Yes not yes or YES

Comment: The data is in column 4 row 3 and the result is in column 4 row 4.

Comment: May this version is better for you.  It allows for different ways of typing Yes.

Comment: Actually maybe I'm missing the point.  Are you saying that you want this script to work whenever column 4 row 3 is edited?